# echo menu_order value in my theme

Tags: menu-order

I thought this would be a simple task, but I cannot find anything on google.

I would simply like to echo the meun_order value in my loop.

I tried this but it's not in the post_meta table, its in the post's table.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu_order', true); ?>
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `get_post_meta` since the `menu_order` is stored in the `posts` table, like you said. But you can set up an easy database query to get the value.

```
$menu_o = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT menu_order FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=" . $post->ID  );
echo $menu_o;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answered similar question here:

[Get current menu_order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84943/get-current-menu-order/205367#205367)

```
get_post_field( 'menu_order', $post_id);
```

or try this inside the loop

```
get_post_field( 'menu_order', $post->ID);
```