# Get current menu_order

Tags: posts, pages, order, menu-order

WordPress implements a simple order functionality by default.

What's the common method, to retrieve the `menu_order` for the current post or page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have the post with an `$id`:

```
$thispost = get_post($id);
$menu_order = $thispost->menu_order;
```

WordPress itself does not provide a function to get the `menu_order`, so you have to query the `post`-Object. If you are outside the loop, you can use the above function, however inside the loop you could also achieve this by:

```
global $post;
$menu_order = $post->menu_order;
```

The Menuorder is mainly used for Database Queries, as the Name says, do determine the Order of the output (if the menuorder is selected to be the order criteria).

Comment: It does not work properly for me, it gets menu order number only for children pages, while for parent pages it is always 0

Answer (score 20):

You can try following code:

```
 get_post_field( 'menu_order', $post_id);
```