# Echo order box (in pages)

Tags: metabox, order, menu-order

How can I echo the value of the order box in posts? See photo.[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: Twenty thirteen

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value from attributes, option page or meta value; if you have an option page you need to call that value: 

`$valuerequired = get_option('ctech_valuefromoptionpage');` 
 ctech is the short theme name, and
if the attributes field is a meta value


`$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);`
 
then you can echo the value with  `echo $price; and echo $valuerequired;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @fernando-baltazar. This makes sense! I'm using twentythirteen, and am trying to take what you used and echo the menu_order box. I have tried this, with no luck: <?php $menuOrder = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu_order', true); echo $menuOrder;  ?>

Comment: @TechyDude
Try using a separated sencence, one to get_post_meta and other for echo, using its own <?php and ?> I´m echoing 15 meta fields with no problems.

Comment: @TechyDude
the other way is <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu_order', true);?>

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: [echo menu_order value in my theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/echo-menu-order-value-in-my-theme)

Should have dug deeper.

```
$menu_o = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT menu_order FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=" . $post->ID  );
```

echo $menu_o;